# No value is present in hidden field after page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have coded in page load.In this i have store regular expressions  in hidRegExp.Value. Now i have to store this value in the hidden field.Now in javascript i have to validate the user input in textbox.But when i enter a value it shows blank alert.But i want to display the regular expression in alert.Pls help me to do this.
code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (FieldTypeInfo == FieldType.TextBox)
        {
            TblSearch.Visible = false;
            TblDate.Visible = false;
            tblDropd.Visible = false;
            TblChk.Visible = false;
            lblText.Text = FieldLabel;
            //txtreq.Enabled = this.IsMandatory;

            string strRegularExp = string.Empty;

            if (ListOfRegularExpression != null)
            {
                for (int iRow = 0; iRow < ListOfRegularExpression.Count; iRow++)
                {
                    strRegularExp += ListOfRegularExpression[iRow].ToString() + "~~";
                    hidRegExp.Value = strRegularExp;
                    if (iRow == ListOfRegularExpression.Count - 1)
                    {                               
                        strRegularExp = strRegularExp.TrimEnd("~~".ToCharArray());
                        txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp('" + txtField.ToString() + "');");
                    }
                }
            }

            hidRegExp.Value = strRegularExp;
            lbl.Text = "The value of the HiddenField control is " + hidRegExp.Value + ".";
        }}
```

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function ValidateRegExp(txtInput) {
        var hiddenValue = document.getElementById("<%=hidRegExp.ClientID%>").value;
        alert("hiddenValue" + hiddenValue+".");
        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = hiddenValue.split("~~");

        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
            //document.write("<br /> Array[" + i + " ]= " + mySplitResult[i]);
             var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
            if (txtInput.match(re)) {
                alert("Successful match");            
            } else {
                alert("No match");
            }
        }     
    }

 </script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp" runat="server" EnableViewState= "true" >
</asp:HiddenField >
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially `ListOfRegularExpression` will be null so control will not enter into `if (ListOfRegularExpression != null)` and `HiddenField.Value` wont be set.

Comment: i have print the value in label but it is not in hidden field

Comment: Try removing `if (!IsPostBack)` it will surely not affect your functionality

Answer (score 0):

I have had the problem before. Honestly, I don't remember how I resolved it, but I tried a few things. Here they are:

For displaying the hidden field, add ClientIdMode as static on your hidden field like

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:HiddenField>
```

and in the JavaScript, use:

```
document.getElementById("hidRegExp");
```

If this does not work, try your approach with these below:

1) Try moving your hidden field before the script.

2) Try making it a label and use that in the JavaScript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can we do in label?Pls post it

Comment: Do the same thing in the label. By using ClientIDMode as Static you force the framework to render the same ID, not the jumbled one. One thing I will say is to avoid using inline code as <%=hidRegExp.ClientID%> in the javascript. Let me know if you stumble again.